# SSL connection using Java standalone app

Tags: java, encryption, ssl

I have created a standalone executable JAR program that needs to send private information over a SSL connection.
I was not able to establish the SSL connection using certificates. Was getting this:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path `building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`
```

So I found some code somewhere that creates a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains:

```
// Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
            new X509TrustManager() {
                public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return null;
                }
                public void checkClientTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
                public void checkServerTrusted(
                    java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                }
            }
        };
```

That did the trick and I was able to establish SSL connection without any certificates.

My concern is if the data will still be encrypted when exchanging private information.
This is an execute JAR file that clients will be downloading to their computers.

So is a certificate really necessary for this case?

Answer (score 4):

It's still encrypted BUT not trustworthy. Best to fix the certificate validation issues instead.

Essentially, SSL provides both encryption and a trust mechanism. You're bypassing the trust part, so the message will still be encrypted, but prone to interception or snooping, using, e.g., a man-in-the-middle attack. A MITM could intercept the request, and complete the SSL handshake using a completely different certificate. They could optionally forward your message to the intended server & back, so you'd never know the message was intercepted.

You should look at downloading the server certificate and putting it into a truststore, which can be loaded at runtime.

See [keytool](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html). 
The keytool executable comes bundled with the JDK, and you can use this command-line tool to create a 'keystore' (in this case, known as a 'truststore'), and import a certificate into it.

There are many ways to tell Java to use a keystore, and your choice depends on what libraries etc you're using to make the SSL connection. 
One method is to use startup options, e.g.:

-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=mySrvKeystore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=123456

Best to google for "keystore java" plus your library name (if you're using one)

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your response, very helpful.  So since this JAR will downloaded/installed into client's computers, I guess there is a way to download the certificate and have it at the keystore.
so the certificate needs to be downloaded and stored in clients computer?  To do this do I have to use native code to execute that keytool command in the clients computer?

Comment: No, you just have to execute the keytool once on your own computer, then deliver the keystore (normally a ..jks file), along with your application. I'm pretty sure you can wrap the keystore into your jar file, and reference it via the classpath

... Sorry to say that Java's ssl client implementation isn't easy to understand, and requires some reading and doing to get along with it ok...

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I have a clear view of what I have to do.

Comment: 'IF the intercepting party had the necessary private key to decrypt the message'. That's not correct. There is no private key to decrypt the message - there is a session key negotiated dynamically between the peers. The problem with that so-called TrustManager is that it prevents you from knowing wo you're talking to. So you have fully secure communications with, err, anybody. SSL is not secure without authentication. See RFC 2246.

Comment: Hi EJP. Yes, SSL does not provide authentication, but to say that 'there is no private key' is just wrong. You are correct in that someone malicious could offer their own certificate (public key), BUT, honestly truly, the message will need to be decrypted using the associated private key. Take a look at this: http://www.verisign.co.uk/ssl/ssl-information-center/how-ssl-security-works/index.html .. if you store the certificate in a keystore, then no-one other than the certificate owner would be able to decrypt your message. Cheers

Comment: The problem is that the given `TrustManager` *doesn't* check against a particular certificate - it will blindly accept *any* certificate from the purported server, which could well be supplied by the man-in-the-middle.

Comment: Thats' what I said at the beginning. "You're bypassing the trust part". Sheesh

Comment: @amir75: SSL uses a session key. The data is not encrypted with the private key. Period. What you describe isn't even possible in the case where only the server has a certificate. The Verisign link is misleading at best and wrong at worst. The authority here is RFC2246, not Verisign's marketing material.

Comment: Perhaps you can submit a more accurate answer? The RFC says that "The server uses its private key to decrypt the pre_master_secret", which suggests that they'd need the private key. Are you saying that the session keys are not public-private pairs? If so, I'm surprised. Please clarify if poss. Ta

Comment: @amir75 The session keys are not public/private pairs. There is only one session key, and it is a symmetric key. This is all in the RFC.

Comment: "*SSL provides 2 types of security: trust and confidentiality.*". The two types of security SSL provides are confidentiality and integration, when the remote party (at least the server) is authenticated: that's what the trust manager and host name verification, and they are essential to the security of the connection.

Comment: @Bruno Hi, yes, my original answer was wayward. I've edited the answer to make it much clearer. Please see if you like it better now. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

With such a trust manager (or with anonymous cipher suites), the connection will still be encrypted (assuming you're not enabling a cipher suite that use a null cipher, which should never be enabled by default).

**However, the client won't know with which entity it is exchanging secret information: it could be a Man-In-The-Middle attacker.**

Encryption isn't enough: you need to know who you're talking to. The client needs to verify that:

- it trusts the server certificate to be genuine (that's the purpose of the trust manager, but not this particular implementation since it never rejects anything),
- this certificate is valid for the host name the client intended to contact.